# Hibernate: Start from Java code the DB layout

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jakarta-ee

Assume the following trivial class:

```
package Sample;  

    public class Status {

        private Long id;
        private String status;

        public Status() {}

        public Status(String status) {
        this.status = status;
        }   

        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public String getStatus() {
            return status;
        }
        public void setStatus(String status) {
            this.status = status;
        }
    }
```

For this class I have defined the hibernate-mapping in the `Status.hbm.xml`.
This file, describes to Hibernate how to map the class to a table.
In the `hibernate.cfg` I have defined how to connect to my Database (MySQL).

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>

        <mapping resource="sample/Status.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

What I do not undertand is the following:
With this configuration when I try to use the `org.hibernate.Session` to save an object of `Status` to the database, it complaints that there is no database to connect.

> 842 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - No
>   database selected

If I add an existing database as part of the URL connection string of `hibernate.cfg.xml` i.e.

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test</property>
```

I get a different error complaining that the table `test.status` does not exist.
I was expecting that Hibernate would create it.
The code is succesfull only if I do:

```
SchemaExport schemaExport = new SchemaExport(cfg);
schemaExport.create(false, true);
```

So my question is, what is the proper process to use Hibernate and create a schema and a database and its tables starting from Java.
I do not want to manually create a database in MySQL for example from an MySQL client.
Is the above approach with the `SchemaExport` the correct way?
What is the best option for the start from Java DB design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having Hibernate create the table structure is fine for testing, but once the application has been deployed to production and is actually running, you will ***NOT*** want hibernate to create the database every time you re-deploy because it will wipe out your data. Getting used to creating `ALTER` scripts for managing database changes is a good habit to get into, since most development is not new but is updating an existing system.

That being said, yes, the way you have indicated *is* the correct way to have Hibernate create the database schema. You can also set that to happen in the Hibernate config file, but I don't remember the property off the top of my head.

Comment: I understand that if Hibernate creates the DB in every redeploy it will erase data.My question was if I want to take an application to production, what is the best way to have hiberate generate the schema and tables and from that point on the application uses the Hibernate generated schema (done only once). Is it impossible?Also the `ALTER` scripts are in the DB level?I.e. not done somehow by Hibernate?

Comment: My preferred way to get the 1st version of my application's database is to let hibernate generate it, and then modify the schema the way I want. This includes things like setting the tables to use InnoDB instead of the default, and adding in proper foreign keys (neither of which Hibernate does by default). I then export this edited schema and use that as my schema for Production. In general, Hibernate should _not_ be manipulating the schema, since that isn't what it's designed for. Let the ORM do only what it's meant for, and that is mapping between the database and code objects.